# Adjust SwiftUI Component from UIKit

Tags: swiftui, uikit

Sometimes I any need to adjust the swiftUI component, so I dive into UIKit and adjust what I need,  for example in the code below I adjust the table view appearance for a specific view, the problem is that effect to all the SwiftUI views the have table view so everything became a big mess, did there is some way to adjust the SwiftUI component for specific view without effect the same component in the other's views.

```
    struct New_EditGroup: View {
            
        init() {
            let tableAppearance = UITableView.appearance()
            tableAppearance.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            tableAppearance.sectionHeaderHeight = 1
            tableAppearance.sectionFooterHeight = 16
            
        }
       
        var body: some View {
    // ...
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just use `Section` Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section. Don't try to use `SwiftUI` like `UIKit`. It would be best to watch the Apple Developer Videos on SwiftUI, learn it from scratch. Don't do a line to line translation from `UIKit` to `SwiftUI` they are completely different frameworks.

Comment: I do this, but there is some adjustments not allowed to do it in SwiftUI you need to use UIKit to do it.

Comment: May be you could edit your exist to show the SwiftUI attempted code and an image what you intend on doing

Comment: Thank you, but this not what I looking for.

Comment: See updated answer with Spacer height

Comment: Thank you very much, its a good trick I can know adjust the section hight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Spacer().frame(height: 16)) {
                    ForEach(1..<10) { element in
                        Text("Element \(element)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main Menu", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Spacer]